# Interface task is synchronous, but I need it to return async

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, interface, shopifysharp

I have downloaded the ShopifySharp project and am trying to make my own executionpolicy by implementing the IRequestExecutionPolicy (https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp/blob/master/ShopifySharp/Infrastructure/Policies/RetryExecutionPolicy.cs).

In the example project there is no such "not implemented error". However, a similar implementation puts this "[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(SmartRetryExecutionPolicy.d__5<>))]" before the method.

From what I can tell, making the method async changes the signature and is therefore not implementing the Run method. I'm not very experienced in this area so any help is appreciated.

```
public delegate Task<RequestResult<T>> ExecuteRequestAsync<T>(CloneableRequestMessage request);

public interface IRequestExecutionPolicy
{
    Task<RequestResult<T>> Run<T>(CloneableRequestMessage requestMessage, ExecuteRequestAsync<T> executeRequestAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken, int? graphqlQueryCost = null);
}
```

```
public class LeakyBucketExecutionPolicy : IRequestExecutionPolicy{
    public LeakyBucketExecutionPolicy(){}

    public async Task<RequestResult<T>> Run<T>(CloneableRequestMessage baseRequest, ExecuteRequestAsync<T> executeRequestAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken, int? graphqlQueryCost = null)
    {
        //retry code
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me when you will use this IRequestExecutionPolicy interface?

Comment: @BrandoZhang ShopifyService.SetGlobalExecutionPolicy(new LeakyBucketExecutionPolicy());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I can tell, making the method async changes the signature

No, it's not. And this is precisely the reason why you will never see `async` in interfaces.

`async` keyword is just so you can do `await`s and `return T` instead of `return Task<T>`. The compiler will wrap it for you. But both the signature, and the way the method is called during the runtime are the same.

Comment: When I updated the library my error disappeared. This answer helped me look for the error in a different spot, thanks!